# Creating a title bar above a tabgroup in Titanium

Tags: android, ios, tabs, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on something in Titanium, and am having some difficulty trying to achieve this.

On the Android version, the `tabgroup` seems to be fixed to the top. I'm fine with that, but I do want the app's logo bar to be above that.

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what Twitter has for their Android app. They have their logo and a compose tweet button that exist above the `tabgroup`. [Here's](http://androinica.com/wp-content/plugins/apps-android/screenshots/com.twitter.android-0.png) a screenshot for clarity:
[image]

Is this even possible? If it can't be done with native `tabGroups`, is there some workaround that I could implement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with a tabGroup in Titanium - they don't have a navBar in Android. With a lot of work, you can create your own by creating a base window, adding tab graphics (view) with click handlers, and they open new windows with a top:  attribute that is below the tabs.  Good luck.

Comment: You can check out my implementation at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.org.mcg.app&hl=en

Comment: Sorry, but I can't share it as it was under NDA. Good luck!

Comment: Sad to hear that, but I guess I'll have to do it. Thanks for clarifying things.